# Azure Authentication in web API - role claims are missing after validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to base user authorization on Azure AD Application Roles in our Web API, but the roles are not translated into actual claims even though i can see them in the token validation response.

I can see the roles in the *ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims* list, but under the property name *roles* and not the claims schema *http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role*.

I have managed to get the Authorization attribute to recognize the role by setting the *RoleClaimType* to *"roles"*.

But how do I make Azure return the roles, or configure the API to interpret them, so that *HasClaim( ClaimTypes.Role, "AdminRole")* returns true?

**Controller.cs**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AdminRole")]
public IEnumerable<Item> Get()
{
    var a = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.HasClaim( ClaimTypes.Role, "AdminRole" ); // false
    var b = User.IsInRole( "AdminRole" ); // true
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth( IAppBuilder app )
{
   app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "ida:Tenant" ],
        TokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "ida:Audience" ],
                RoleClaimType = "roles" // makes this work: User.IsInRole( "AdminRole" )
            }
    } );
}
```

**Azure Portal**

- Registered the Web API and native WPF Client Application, and modified the manifest for the Web Api to include a couple of roles. *"Azure
  Portal / App Registrations / Edit manifest"*
- Added/Assigned a few users to the Web Api application and specified
  one role or another. *"Azure Portal / Enterprise Applications / [Name of Application] - Users and groups"*

For all who read this far - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claims emitted by Azure AD are of type "roles", you will need to set the RoleClaimType(in TokenValidationParameters) as `roles` , then you could make below validations work :

```
    var a = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.HasClaim("roles", "AdminRole"); 
    var b = User.IsInRole("AdminRole");
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why AAD emits roles instead of the longer http://.../role that seems to be expected?

Comment: Sorry , i don't know why .